# ValidationError: Validation failed mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, oauth-2.0, passport.js

Hello I am trying to connect Node.js with Facebook. I am following [this](http://jeroenpelgrims.com/token-based-sessionless-auth-using-express-and-passport/) blog entry.
Can someone help me?

I am gettin this error:

> ValidationError: Validation failed    at model.Document.invalidate
>   (/Users/me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:1009:32)    at
>   /Users/me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:958:16    at validate
>   (/Users/me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:610:7)    at
>   /Users/me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:627:9    at
>   Array.forEach (native)    at SchemaString.SchemaType.doValidate
>   (/Users/me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/schematype.js:614:19)    at
>   /Users/me/node_modules/mongoose/lib/document.js:956:9    at
>   doNTCallback0 (node.js:419:9)    at process._tickCallback
>   (node.js:348:13)

```
 var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
    var BearerStrategy  = require('passport-http-bearer').Strategy;
    var passport = require('passport');
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

    // Mongoose connection to MongoDB (ted/ted is readonly)
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testDB', function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    });

    var userSchema = new Schema({
        facebookId: String,
        access_token: {
                type: String
            },
        profileImage : String,
        email : {
            type : String,

            unique : true
        },
        password : {
            type : String,

        },
        created_at : Date,
        updated_at : Date
    });


        userSchema.statics.findOrCreate = function(filters, cb) {
            User = this;
            this.find(filters, function(err, results) {
                if(results.length == 0) {
                    var newUser = new User();
                    newUser.facebookId = filters.facebookId;
                    newUser.save(function(err, doc) {
                        cb(err, doc);
                    });
                } else {
                    cb(err, results[0]);
                }
            });
        };

    //facebook auth setup
        options = {
             clientID: 'FB_ID',
     clientSecret: 'FB_SecretKey',
     callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback'

        };
     passport.use(
            new FacebookStrategy(
                options,
                function(accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
                    User.findOrCreate(
                        { facebookId: profile.id },
                        function (err, result) {
                            if(result) {
                                result.access_token = accessToken;
                                result.save(function(err, doc) {
                                    done(err, doc);
                                });
                            } else {
                                done(err, result);
                            }
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
        );

        app.get(
            '/auth/facebook',
            passport.authenticate('facebook', { session: false, scope: [] })
        );

         app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
            passport.authenticate('facebook', { session: false, failureRedirect: "/" }),
            function(req, res) {
                res.redirect("/");
            }
        );

        //token auth setup
        passport.use(
            new BearerStrategy(
                function(token, done) {
                    User.findOne({ access_token: token },
                        function(err, user) {
                            if(err) {
                                return done(err);
                            }
                            if(!user) {
                                return done(null, false);
                            }

                            return done(null, user, { scope: 'all' });
                        }
                    );
                }
            )
        );
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "testapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description" : "Something"

  "engines": {
    "node": "4.2.x",
    "npm": "3.3.x",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.12.0",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.4",
    "debug": "~2.1.1",
    "express": "~4.12.2",
    "fs-extra": "^0.18.4",
    "jade": "~1.9.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "5.0.4",
    "morgan": "~1.5.1",
    "multer": "^1.0.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Now I changed the required fields and I am not getting the error.

Comment: Have you started the mongodb shell server?

Comment: yes I did. Otherwise I would get an exception which I have implmenented.

Comment: When you get `Validation failed` it means you're trying to save something that doesn't match your schema. The only place you are saving anything (in this code) is `profile.id` in the Facebook strategy. It's probably not a string.

Comment: Yes, I am getting a number like this: 10404282581118299. I changed in my schema the type into number and also schmema.mixed but it appears the same validate problem. I also print the type of profile.id console.log(typeof(profile.id)+  "profileID"); and it is a string.

Comment: Oh, I see. You have email and password as required fields, but you're creating a new user with only a `profile.id`

Answer (score 0):

```
password : {
        type : String, // <-- no 

    }
```

that could be a reasons

Comment: I think that would cause a syntax error, not the validation fail error OP is seeing.